# Nested Buffers - Opening external sourcecode files inside org-mode codeblocks

Tags: org-mode

How to open external sourcecode files inside org-mode codeblocks, in a way that files can be viewed and saved while saving the org-mode document.

Kinda of a 'Nested Buffers' feature?

Comment: I've never heard of a way to do this, but it sounds like a nice feature. Currently when you save a buffer it does not know that one of the headings is connected to another file and to save that separately. I could imagine that you could write something that would save a heading into a file, and then add-hook when saved to call that function. I assume "viewed and saved" means "viewed, edited and saved"

Comment: I am doing some reading in Literate programming with emacs, I hope to find someone done what I am after, before. Shall update then (could take awhile as I am busy with other stuff)

Comment: Ah, I see, yes you could have it export to a file, but that's a one-way street. If you modify the file outside, it won't be read back in. For what you described you would want a hook to do the export upon save of the org file.

Comment: @jtgd yup, exactly

Comment: Would you like me to write it for you?

Comment: @jtgd if you can share it as a gist or as an elisp package that would be AWESOME!! please do, and I will be happy to share any modifications that seems to be nice as well.

Comment: I would ask you questions about the particulars of the implementation, but I see no way to send messages through StackExchange.

Comment: @jtgd thanks again, I am simply having a single page blog where I want my codesnippets to exist on their own and I just update them from the single org file.  

Extremely minimalistic approach, many would argue to do things differently for various reasons, and most of the time they are right, but I am lazy, and thats for me.

Comment: @jtgd whats your irc nick on freenode, maybe we can chat on #emacs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a few variations and options one might want to add, but this seems to work for me. Try it, @zotherstupidguy, and get back to me with suggestions.

Upon saving the org file it will look for any heading containing a property of `SAVE-TO-FILE` whose value is the filename to save to, i.e.:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:SAVE-TO-FILE: ~/my-ext-file
:END:
```

It will save everything in that heading, including the heading itself and the property drawer.

```
(defun save-headings-external ()
"Save all heading containing special property to an external file"
(interactive)
(when (string= major-mode "org-mode")
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let (-extfname -start)
    (while (re-search-forward ":PROPERTIES:" nil t)
      (when (setq -extfname (org-entry-get (point) "SAVE-TO-FILE"))
        (save-excursion
          (org-back-to-heading)
          (setq -start (point))
          (org-forward-heading-same-level 1 t)
          (write-region -start (point) -extfname)
          (message "Wrote '%s'" -extfname)))))))

(add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'save-headings-external)
```

(You can delete the `(message...)` if you want)